# Adding UIImageView to UITableview conditionally using SDWebImage

Tags: ios, uitableview, reusability, sdwebimage

I'm using SDWebImage Library to download images for UIImageView in UITableView. The content of my tableview is an array initialized in viewDidLoad as shown below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.myArray =@[@"http://i.imgur.com/CUwy8ME.jpg",@"http://i.imgur.com/lQRlubz.jpg",@"AlAhmed",@"Welcome",@"jfhskjh",@"hfyyu",@"lkdjfs",@"mfjsoi",@"jsdkjhdksjh",@"ljsdkfhuhs"];

[self.tableView setRowHeight:100];

[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

My idea is to detect if an URL exists in myArray and hence to download the image in that cell. My code works fine but the images are shown in other cells (I think of reusing cells), but I couldn't solve the problem.

And here's the code for tableview delegate

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:           (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Celll";
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView       dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

UIImageView *imgView=nil;
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,0,100,62)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
}


NSError *error;
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:&error];

NSString *myString = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:myString
                                     options:0
                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, [myString length])];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) {
        NSURL *url = [match URL];

        [imgView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"120.png"] completed:^(UIImage *image,NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType){
        }];
    }

}


[ cell.textLabel setText:[self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


return cell;
}
```

Please I need your great help.

Comment: As @Putz mentioned ideally you should use Custom TableCell class, but adding the UIImageView subView on cell's contentView and retrieving with tag will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to have to subclass UITableViewCell and add `imgView` as a class variable.  Then in your `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` you can check the cell returned to see if `imgView` already exists.  Then you can either update or remove the imgView based on your checks.

As you have it now you are adding an imageView to the cell's contentView.  Then that cell gets re-used (still having the old imageView contained in it) and you add another imageView.  This will be a memory nightmare very shortly.

EDIT: Now with code! (and 33% less fat!)

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;

@end

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:           (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Celll";
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView       dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

UIImageView *imgView=nil;
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

if(cell.imageView)
{
    cell.imageView.image = nil;
}
else
{
    cell.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,0,100,62)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.imageView];
}


NSError *error;
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:&error];

NSString *myString = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:myString
                                     options:0
                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, [myString length])];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) {
        NSURL *url = [match URL];

        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"120.png"] completed:^(UIImage *image,NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType){
        }];
    }

}


[ cell.textLabel setText:[self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


return cell;
}
```

So you remove the image if it's already loaded into the cell then worry about reloading it the same way you currently are.  This makes it so if you ever want to update the image you have an easy handle to it for modifications.

Comment: Thanks for your help, could you please show me an example code for your solution ?

Comment: @user1887971 updated with a bit of code.  You should be able to take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your suggestions. I created a subclass of UITableViewCell called CustomClass.h/.m and I created CusstomCell.xib and then added an UITableViewCell Object to the nib file with UIImageView added to the Cell.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImageView;
```

Then I have edited my code as follows and it work perfectly.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *customCellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
CustomCell *myCell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customCellIdentifier];
if (myCell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    myCell = [nib lastObject];
}

   NSURL *url =[self LookForURLinString:[self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
if (url) {
    [myCell.myImageView setImageWithURL:url
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"120.png"]
                              completed:^(UIImage *image,NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType){}];
}
else {
    [myCell.myImageView setImage:nil];
    [myCell.myImageView removeFromSuperview];
}
[myCell.textLabel setText:[self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
return myCell;


}
-(NSURL *)LookForURLinString:(NSString *)string
{
NSError *error;
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:&error];



NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:string
                                     options:0
                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) {
        NSURL *url = [match URL];
        return url;
    }
}
return nil;

}
```